# Lookup within range and increment counter

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to reorganized some data and create unique IDS to them by using a data in the `"Date Column"` and doing a increment count of the year. I wanted to get the last 2 digits of the year from the `"Date Column"` then after to do an dash (-) followed by a count. Is this do-able in a vba or just a standard formula? If so how?
Below is an example:

```
-----------------------------
Date        | Desired Result
----------------------------
1/2/2001    | 01-0001
1/3/2001    | 01-0002
5/4/2001    | 01-0003
9/1/2002    | 02-0001
8/9/2003    | 03-0001
10/30/2003  | 03-0003
12/31/2005  | 05-0001
5/6/2006    | 06-0001
5/7/2006    | 06-0002
5/8/2006    | 06-0003
7/9/2006    | 06-0004
8/10/2006   | 06-0005
11/11/2006  | 06-0006
12/12/2006  | 06-0007
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in B2 and fill down.

```
=TEXT(A2, "yy")&TEXT(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2, ">="&DATE(YEAR(A2), 1, 1), A$2:A2, "<"&DATE(YEAR(A2)+1, 1, 1)), "-0000")
```

[image]